# Proving that Lagrange Polynomials of degree n-1 are orthogonal to eachother

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods

> Let $\phi_0(x),\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),...$ be a sequence of orthogonal polynomials on an interval $[a,b]$ w.r.t a positive weight function $w(x)$. Let $x_1,....,x_n$ be the n zeros of $\phi_n(x)$' it is known that these roots are real and $a<x_1<...<x_n<b$
>
> Show that the Lagrange polynomials of degree n-1 based on these points are orthogonal to each other, so we can write
> $$\int_a^b w(x) L_j(x)L_k(x)dx=0; \hspace{5mm} j \neq k,$$
> where
> $$L_j(x) = \prod_{k=1,k \neq j}^n \frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}, \hspace{5mm} 1\leq j \leq n$$

My attempt:

Denote $x= x_i$. Therefore we have $L_j(x_i)$ and $L_k(x_i)$. Since $j \neq k$, we see that when $i = j$ by defn $L_j(x_j) = 1$ and $L_k(x_j) = 0$, likewise when $i=k$, by defn, $L_j(x_k) = 0$ and $L_k(x_k) = 1$.  When $i \neq k$ and $i \neq j$, it follows that $L_j(x_i) = L_k(x_i) = 0$

Thus it follows that $L_j(x)L_k(x) = 0 \rightarrow \int_a^b w(x) L_j(x)L_k(x)dx=0 $ $\forall j,k$ Therefore the Lagrange polynomials are orthogonal to each other.

I was talking to my classmates, and they said this proof was not correct since I did not take into account continuity. I am not sure what they mean by this. What am I missing here?

Comment: You establish that for $n-2$ particular points (namely all but two of the values $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ you have $L_1(x)L_2(x)=0$. I don't see how that helps you to evaluate the integral  $\int_a^bw(x)L_1(x)L_2(x)\ dx$. The value of the integral is unaffected by the value of the integrand at *any* finite number of points. Also your approach would imply that it made no difference what weight function $w(x)$ was used. From a different point of view, you make no use of the $\phi_i(x)$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use distributions to compose the weight? Then $w(x)=\sum \delta(x-x_i)$ would do the job, see [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: Not just for $L_1(x)L_2(x)$, but for all $L_i(x)L_j(x)$ for $i \neq j$. The question assumes the weight function is positive, so $w(x)*0 = 0$ for any weight function no? So in this case you are simply integrating over $0$ which is just $0$. I understand though in the case of only taking finitely many points, but don't we only care about the $n$ zeros of the orthogonal polynomials?

Comment: $L_i(x)L_j(x)$ with $i\neq j$ is not $0$ for all $x\in[a,b].$ It is $0$ only for $x\in\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}.$ So if you choose the wrong weight function, your integral will not be $0$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But isn't choosing only a specific weight function defeating the purpose of proving orthogonality?

Comment: Finding the weigh function is the difficult part, here. You will not easily find a weight function for which the integral evaluates to the desired values ($0$ in case of $i\neq j$, $1$ in case $i=j$) But as soon as you have found a weight function that fulfills all requirements, you have proved orthogonality. The polynomials are then orthogonal with respect to this specific weight function.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting the problem, but isn't it asking to show that the Lagrange polynomials are orthogonal for any arbitrary positive weight function?

Comment: It can easily be shown that this does not hold, not even for $n=2$

Comment: It appears the dirac delta function cannot be used. Any other avenues I could pursue for $w(x)$?

Comment: Hello, I just wonder if you solved this problem.  I was thinking that if we might express, say $L_j(x)$, in terms of the basis $\phi_0,...,\phi_n$, we will have the result although it is not a reasonable approach.

Comment: Hi Charles, if I remember correctly, there is some trick in expressing $Lj(x)$ as the quotient of some strategic choice polynomial of degree less than $n$. It has been a while but I hope that helps you somewhat.